# HTML read local file not selected by user

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to update a number on a website from a file on my computer that will be changing. 
Is there a way to read this local file using html/javascript so that I can update the website. 
Most things I have found give examples of where the user uploads a file, however this number is going to be changing very often so I cannot use that way. 
Thanks

here is some of the code i've tried:
      fs = require('fs');
              contents = fs.readFileSync('test.txt').toString();
              if(num !== contents)
              {
                hitCount.textContent = contents;
               }

```
jQuery.get('test.txt',function(data){document.write(data);
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Websites cannot access arbitrary files on the computer the browser is running on. That would be a terrible security risk.

It sounds like you would be better off cutting the browser out entirely. Possibly using Node.js or WSH if you want to use JavaScript to perform your updates.